# Add function to PHP file_get_contents path

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have this snippet of code which grabs the source of an SVG image and adds it to the HTML:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("assets/images/lightening.svg"); ?>
```

I want to add a function root(); (that I already have working) which to the beginning path which tells it where the root of the site it (I'm hoisting the site in multiple locations).

What I want is a version of this that works:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("'root();'.assets/images/lightening.svg"); ?>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: file_get_contents(root().'.assets/images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependent on whether the function `root()` returns the path without trailing slath:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(root() . "/assets/images/lightening.svg"); ?>
```

or with trailing slash:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(root() . "assets/images/lightening.svg"); ?>
```

Comment: This works fine when my root has a good path, but when the root is just "/" it fails and prints out the "/" before the image, any thoughts?

Comment: @James, without restructuring your code, you could do `echo file_get_contents((root() === '/' ? '/' : root()) . "assets/images/lightening.svg");`